# time operator in jsonpath kubectl

Tags: kubectl, jsonpath

I set label "mytime" in timestemp format for my pod. Now i want select all pods with expired time? some think like this:

`kubectl get pods -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels.mytime<$now()}{.metadata.name}{ "\n"}{end}'`

but i see error

```
error: error executing jsonpath "{range .items[*]}{.metadata.labels.mytime<$now()}{.metadata.name}{ \"\\n\"}{end}": Error executing template: unrecognized identifier now(). Printing more information for debugging the template:
        template was:
                {range .items[*]}{.metadata.creationTimestamp>$now()}{.metadata.name}{ "\n"}{end}
        object given to jsonpath engine was: ...
```

how use time in condition?

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick for me:

I couldn't get the result with now, may be due to the difference in format.

```
kubectl get pods -o=jsonpath="{range .items[?(@.metadata.labels.mytime<=\"2022-12-19\")]}[{.metadata.labels.mytime},{.metadata.namespace},{.metadata.name}] {end}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl -n test get deployment -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.labels.mytime<"2020-10-08_14-15-07")].metadata.name}'
```